# How is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I know this question will get down-voted to the underworld, as many often mistake my confusion and want to learn for arrogance. I am not saying my question was unrightfully put on hold, I'm simply saying I don't understand why, and I'll provide points that fuel my confusion.

I read a little up: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Under **Applied Philosophy**, there is *theology*, in addition to there being a *Christianity* tag. I also let everyone know my intentions with the post were non-religious.

A belief I think might've contributed to the question being put on hold is that the question isn't within philosophy, but rather religion. It goes without saying that those two aren't mutually exclusive, and this question is definitely an overlapping place. I was asking about a component of a Christian concept that **is very much up for interpretation.** In fact, it has been interpreted many times, and as such there are many sources to bring in. One can also bring in scientific elements (psychology, neurology, sociology, etc), in addition to applying other, existing philosophies to cracking the nut that is this question, and of course, utilizing one's own understanding of the world and the concept.

All in all, I think it is a helpful question, definitely within philosophy, and I don't understand why it was put on hold. Could someone explain why?

Here is the question:

[The Full Scope of Sloth](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67743/the-full-scope-of-sloth)

Comment: For starters that's really far too long for a question. It's fifteen paragraphs! Few questions should be longer than five, and most are only 1-3. Second, you start by saying "I want to discuss the scope of what Sloth means", and I think that's indicative: this site is not a place for discussion as we typically think of it from internet forums. It is a place only for tightly focused questions and answers.